# Upload and insert into text area

Tags: jquery

I have wrote a very simple php upload. But I want to insert image in text area with "click". I want to do this with jquery.

[image]
[image]

Is there any jquery plugin for do this? (or an application for upload like in stackoverflow)?
Thanks in advance

Comment: You can't embed HTML within a textarea. You might want to look into a `contenteditable` div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After submit (some help about that in [here](http://www.9lessons.info/2011/08/ajax-image-upload-without-refreshing.html#comment-form)) call to the rich text area and insert the img tag, something like this:

```
$('#imageform').bind('submit', function(e) {
   e.preventDefault(); // <-- important
   $(this).ajaxSubmit({
      target: '#preview',
      success: function() {
            $('#richtext_area').html('<img id"newimg" src="" alt="your file"/>');
            $('#newimg').attr("src",$("#filePath_text").val())
         }              
   });
}).submit();
```

Answer (score 2):

Check http://elrte.org/. It's a jQuery WYSIWYG editor with files manager.

Comment: Thanks! I know elrte, Its awesome, but I want to learn about making such applications.

Answer (score 1):

Look up TinyMCE - it's not part of jQuery, but, it's a JS library that gives you a WYSIWYG editor with image control.

Answer (score 1):

Try [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/demo), it's even working with jQuery too.